# How to bind Mask properties for TextEdit in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, devexpress

I'm trying to set up a TextEdit box in my WPF project, but I have some problems with my mask.

XAML:

```
     <dxe:TextEdit x:Name="dxTextEdit" 
                   Height="23" MinWidth="200" Width="Auto"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                   Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}"
                   MaskType="RegEx" 
                   MaxLength="{Binding InputLength}"
                   Mask="{Binding Mask, Mode=TwoWay}"
                   />
```

Where Mask returns a string like "[a-zA-Z0-9]" and InputLength returns a value. I cannot insert anything in the box or I can insert one character at best. The thing is, the mask works just fine in my SpinEdit box, which is coded like this:

XAML:

```
     <dxe:SpinEdit x:Name="dxSpinEdit" 
                   Height="23" MinWidth="200" Width="Auto"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                   Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}"
                   MaskType="Numeric"
                   IsFloatValue="{Binding FloatValue}"
                   MinValue="{Binding MinValue}"
                   MaxValue="{Binding MaxValue}"
                   Mask="{Binding Mask, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                   MaxLength="{Binding Path=InputLength}"
                   MaskShowPlaceHolders="{Binding ShowPlaceHolder}"
                   InvalidValueBehavior="WaitForValidValue"
                   MaskUseAsDisplayFormat="True"
                   AllowRoundOutOfRangeValue="True"
                   />
```

Where Mask returns strings like "d", "n0"

I need to be able to bind input length and a sting that defines my mask inside xaml. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I went through most of the devexpress forums and I found something like this: Mask="([a-zA-Z0-9]|\s){0,31}" but it doesn't allow me to modify the length or the regex.

Comment: try `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`

Comment: @ASh I tried that and I cannot type anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In masked mode, the [TextEdit.MaxLength](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.Editors.TextEditBase.MaxLength.property) property is not operational and must be set to 0. In this instance, the number of characters an end-user can enter is specified by the editor's mask.
Take a look at [Quantifiers](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/6949/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Editors/Common-Features/Masked-Input/Mask-Type-Extended-Regular-Expressions#quant) section of [Mask Type: Extended Regular Expressions](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/6949/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Editors/Common-Features/Masked-Input/Mask-Type-Extended-Regular-Expressions) help article to learn how to create an appropriate mask:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,_} // you should replace _ with the exact length value
```